# use pinia vue to filter a query

Tags: vue.js, quasar, pinia

my goal is to bring customers who have the groups id passed

The customers current state

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Cliente 1",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Proprietário"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Inquilino"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Cliente 2",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Proprietário"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

pass the id through the function

```
cStore.getTiposClientes(selectionTipo.value);
```

I receive at

```
getTypeCustomers: (state) => {
  return (id) => state.customers.filter();
},
```

Comment: Your explanation isn't very clear.  Do you mean you want to filter the customers array by group id?  What is `selectionTipo.value`? Is that the group value?  Does `getTiposClientes` call `getTypeCustomers`?

Comment: Your explanation isn't very clear. Do you mean you want to filter the customers array by group id? ..... yes  -  selectionTipo.value ----- 1 yes ----

Comment: it's wrong >>>>getTiposClientes  ----- correct ----- getTypeCustomers

Answer (score 2):

You just add getters like this :

```
getTypeCustomers: (state) => {
  return (id) => state.customers.filter((data)=>data.id==id);
},
```

and call it like this :

```
<script setup>
  import { customersStore } from './store'
  const customers = customersStore()
  const { getTypeCustomers } = storeToRefs(customers)
</script>
<template>
  <p>User 2: {{ getTypeCustomers(2) }}</p>
</template>
```